# Continually looping python code so it will not end

Tags: python, loops

Im trying to make it so that even after I give the input to the "enter a command", the code will bring me back to the option to give input after displaying what the last input was. For example i would like it to display the "enter a command" prompt continually after previously done. 
Is there a way to loop the code back without it ever ending?

```
c1 = "p"
c2 = "d"
c3 = "t"

command = ""
while command != c1:
    print("Enter a command: ")
    print ("(P)profile / (D)data ")
    command = input()
    if command == c1 or command == c2:
        print ("loading...")

        time.sleep(3)

        if command == c1:
            print ("User: Student")
        if command == c2:
            print ("ID: 111111111")

        time.sleep(1)  

    print ("Enter a command: ")
    print ("(P)profile / (D)data ")
    command = input()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put everything in a `while True` loop and remove the last 3 lines where you are printing and asking for input (since you're already asking for the input at the beginning) 
This should work:

```
c1 = "p"
c2 = "d"
c3 = "t"

while True:
    print("Enter a command: ")
    print ("(P)profile / (D)data ")

    command = input()
    if command == c1 or command == c2:
        print ("loading...")

        time.sleep(3)

        if command == c1:
            print ("User: Student")
        if command == c2:
            print ("ID: 111111111")

        time.sleep(1)
```